# Printing out unqualified name of a generic like Union in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

How would I print out the unqualified name of a generic type in Python?

I.E.

```
print(Union.__name__)
```

Leads to: `AttributeError: '_SpecialForm' object has no attribute '__name__'`

```
print(str(Union))
```

Leads to: `'typing.Union'`

I want just: `'Union'`

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What's the usecase for this?

Comment: I want to codegen some Python based on the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the `_name` attribute:

`Union._name` -> `"Union"`

In the future you can inspect an objects attributes with the `dir` function, i.e. `dir(Union)`.